# How do I retrieve the object a method handle is bound to?

Tags: python, python-3.x, introspection

Given a method handle in Python 3, how do I retrieve the object it is part of?

```
class Myclass:
    def foo(self):
        print(self, 'foo')

m = Myclass()

method_handle = m.foo
print(method_handle) # -> <bound method Myclass.foo of <__main__.Myclass object at 0x7fb80220dd10>>
```

The `method_handle` object has a reference to the `m` instance somewhere. But if I only have the `method_handle`, how do I retrieve the `m` object?

Answer (score 2):

Never mind, I just found it: it is in `method_handle.__self__`.